# Google app script,gmail addon remove user properties while uninstall addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-contextual-gadgets, gmail-addons

I have create simple gmail addon using google script,in that i have struggle here,

i have used UserProperties,the problem is, i have store some user level script values.while uninstall addon,we need remove UserProperties

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is an uninstall event. According to the docs it is not listed in the Add-on lifecycle or the list add-on triggers.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle