# When user delete spreadsheet add-on, the document properties store added with the add-on continues to remain?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I'm developing Google Sheets Add-on.

I was just wandering that the document properties store is deleted when users uninstall the add-on.
GAS don't have Trigger like 'onUninstalled'.
If the properties continue to remain, I don't know where I write the program that delete them.

Who knows my problem??

Comment: You'd need to inform the user that they need to delete the settings before uninstalling the add-on, and provide a way to do that from your add-on.  Or you could save all the settings to a text file, or in a separate sheet tab, or in another spreadsheet and not save anything to Properties Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned in a comment, the properties (script, document, user) aren't deleted when the user uninstall the add-on.

You might add a way for users to delete the properties and warn them that the data stored in properties should be deleted before uninstalling the add-on.

Related

- [Handling persistent user-specific values in Gmail Add-ons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48561117/1595451)
- [Google app script,gmail addon remove user properties while uninstall addon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48779952/1595451)
- [How to delete User Property Services when User deletes G-Suite Add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63351124/1595451)